# url_encode function does not appear to be working with spaces in Twig

Tags: twig

I am using the url_encode function on a button, but it does not appear to be working with space characters.

```
<script>
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "foo.php?bar={{ bar|url_encode }}";
    });
</script>
...
<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="foo">
```

When bar = "Da Tang" the URL comes out to be:

```
foo.php?bar=Da Tang
```

What am I missing?  I was expecting "+" or "%20" in the URL instead of the space character.

Comment: How do you verify the output. Above [snippet](https://twigfiddle.com/80zno5) seems to be working OK

Comment: I look at the address bar in my browser.

Comment: That is not the right aproach. Browers tend not to display the `%20` but it is there. If I surf to www.example.com?test=foo%20bar on firefox (51.0.X) the `%20` won't be visible either

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!